# req.session.name is undefiened even if when logging out

Tags: node.js

The server (just linking routes and setting middlewares):

```
const express = require('express')
const {routes} = require('./routes')
const app = express()
const PORT = 3001
const session = require('express-session');

const connect_front_end = require('body-parser')

app.use(connect_front_end.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(connect_front_end.json());
app.use(session({
    secret: 'your-secefwewfret-key', // Change this to a secure, random string
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { secure: false } // Set to true if using HTTPS
}));
app.set('views', './src/views/');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use('/', routes);

app.listen(PORT, ()=>{
    console.log('escutando a porta 3001')
})
```

The routes:

```
const express = require('express');
const routes = express.Router();

routes.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    if(req.session.name){
        res.send('You are already logged')
    }else{
        res.render('./login/init')
    }
})

routes.get('/cadastro',(req,res)=>{//sign up
    res.render('./cadastro/cadastro')
})

routes.post('/autenticar',(req,res)=>{//if auth is ok
    if(req.body.login!='davi'){
        res.render('./login/fail')
    }
    else{
        res.render('./logged/home')
        req.session.name = 'Davi américo'
    }
})

routes.get('/logout',(req,res)=>{
    req.session.destroy();
    res.redirect('/');
})

module.exports = {
    routes
}
```

The main problem was... after login is poorly authorized (just for testing) req.session.name is falsy when going to '/', if I switch to if(req.session) so req.session is truthy but when logging out the session is still truthy and persistant cant logging out. I tried to set req.session to null, I also tried to change secrete key, even open private mode in my webbrowser but I get nothing